# Can't execute war - file: "no main manifest attribute"

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, war

i have created a jsp project with webservice in netbeans and i have created a war file to implement it in the AWS but while executing the command "java -jar filename.war it is showing some error

no main manifest attribute, in Hurling_Server.war

root@ip-172-31-21-53:/home/ubuntu# java -jar Hurling_Server.war
no main manifest attribute, in Hurling_Server.war

Answer (score 0):

How you can execute/use the WAR file depends on what it contains and how you have packaged it. WAR files are web archives meant to be deployed in server containers like Tomcat, Jetty, etc.

If this is a regular WAR, deploy it in a server like Tomcat, Jetty and access the web application.

Have you bundled an embedded server like Tomcat or Jetty in the WAR? If yes then most likely it is already executable depending on how you have created the WAR in the first place. If not embedded nay server then, you have to add the `MANIFEST.MF` under `META-INF/`. And in the manifest file you have to specify the main class name like:

```
Main-Class:mypackage1.mypackage2.MyExecutableClass
```

The WAR structure should look like:

```
mypackage1/mypackag2/MyExecutableClass
WEB-INF/lib
WEB-INF/classes
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

With embedded Jetty the MANIFEST and executable main class are placed the following way in WAR:

```
jetty/bootstrap/JettyBootstrap.class
jetty/bootstrap/LiveWarClassLoader.class
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

So, why your WAR file is not executing depends on several factors mentioned above. Please check.